# when starting light-oauth2 images, it shows no route handler provider available in service.yml

Tags: oauth-2.0, light-4j

I just run the light-oauth2 in docker-toolbox, but none of the images have been started, it mentioned: "no route handler provider available in service.yml". What the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, there is no built-in default configuration files packaged into the light-oauth2 services. This is required by one of the banking customers and we think it is a good idea although it is a little bit harder for users to get it started.

If you want to start the light-oauth2 in a Kubernetes or Openshift cluster, you can follow the configuration in this repository.

https://github.com/networknt/light-config-test/tree/master/light-oauth2

If you want to start the light-oauth2 with docker-compose, you can find configuration files for different databases in light-docker repository. The docker-compose files can be found in the root directory.

https://github.com/networknt/light-docker/tree/master/light-oauth2

For more information, please refer to the tutorials at

https://doc.networknt.com/tutorial/oauth/

Comment: Hi, @Steve, I found the config file has been there in the docker-compose-oauth2-mysql.yml file as below :       

    volumes:- ./light-oauth2/mysql/config/oauth2-code:/config

Comment: Yes. All configuration files for different databases are located in the light-oauth2 folder in the light-docker repository. You can customize it for your needs based on one of the databases you preferred.